# Visual Studio 2022 - Solution Explorer not populating - Failed to create view with exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022, comexception, solution-explorer

I tried to open an existing older .NET 4.8 REST API solution in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.4.  I got this interesting error where the Solution Explorer pane did not load, and instead was populated with the following exception message:

"Failed to create view with exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): The hierarchy is not in a valid state. Make sure that the product is installed properly."

This project has MVC, Razor and EntityFramework.  It's an older project, not built by me, so I don't have a whole lot of other info to share on it.  This is the first time I have gotten this error.

I was expecting to see my solution load into Solution Explorer per the norm.  I didn't try anything to resolve it outside of what I have shared below as an Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am answering my own question here.  The solution was to install the latest version of Visual Studio 2022.  I went to the Help dropdown menu at the top of the Visual Studio window, and chose Check for Updates.
[image: Help - Check for Updates]

Then I followed the prompts to install the latest version, which was 17.5.4.

After these updates installed, I opened the solution again, and the solution loaded normally into Solution Explorer.

Comment: This answer still worked when I had the issue in 17.8.4 and upgraded to 17.8.6